# Is it possible to share text with html <a href> attribute in android intent?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to implement sharing mechanism for sharing a specific text which is including  attribute (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

Below is something that I've tried so far:

```
   val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        shareIntent.type = "text/html"
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some testing with link which should appear <a href=\"www.google.com\">here</a>, but it isn't :(")

   activity.startActivity(shareIntent)
```

Text is appearing in Gmail without HTML formatting (just plain text like below):

```
Some testing with link which should appear <a href\"www.google.com\">here</a>, but it isn't :(
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    shareIntent.type = "text/html"
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("Some testing with link which should appear <a href\"www.google.com\">here</a>, but it isn't :(", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))

    startActivity(shareIntent)
```

put your text in intent like that and it should work

Comment: unfortunately it is not working as expected. Text appears without HTML (which is something improved) but without linking. So just: "Some testing with link which should appear here, but it isn't :("

Comment: one step forward :D I will try to find solution for that